# Integrate Vue3, typescript with AEM

Tags: typescript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, aem

Am trying to integrate Typescript with Vue3 in AEM project and didn't work as expected
when i build i get this error in Terminal

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webpack/components/navigation/FlyoutNavigation.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=ts (./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js!./node_modules/glob-import-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-1.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0]!./src/main/webpack/components/navigation/FlyoutNavigation.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=ts) 3:9-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.' in '/Users/sayedsayed/Projects/codered/brandhub/bran/ui.frontend/src/main/webpack/components/navigation'
resolve '.' in '/Users/sayedsayed/Projects/codered/brandhub/bran/ui.frontend/src/main/webpack/components/navigation'
  using description file: /Users/sayedsayed/Projects/codered/brandhub/bran/ui.frontend/package.json (relative path: ./src/main/webpack/components/navigation)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /Users/sayedsayed/Projects/codered/brandhub/bran/ui.frontend/package.json (relative path: ./src/main/webpack/components/navigation)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/sayedsayed/Projects/codered/brandhub/bran/ui.frontend/src/main/webpack/components/navigation is not a file
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/sayedsayed/Projects/codered/brandhub/bran/ui.frontend/src/main/webpack/components/navigation.js doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/sayedsayed/Projects/codered/brandhub/bran/ui.frontend/src/main/webpack/components/navigation.ts doesn't exist
      .vue
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/sayedsayed/Projects/codered/brandhub/bran/ui.frontend/src/main/webpack/components/navigation.vue doesn't exist
      as directory
```

trying to add configuration to webpack to make it work with typescript but get this error in console when add lang="ts" to vue script[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding this property to webpack config rules solved the problem for me

```
{
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
            },
},
```